# How to define propertynames for GetFeatureInfo

Tags: geoserver, getfeatureinfo

We make a GetFeatureInfo call to a GeoServer and expect a geojson return.
Is it possible to define human-readable property names?
something like: baujahr -> Baujahr
or eigentuemer_organisationstyp -> Eigentümer Organisationstyp

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "paa_leitung_oe.12989",
      "geometry_name": "verlauf",
      "properties": {
        "baujahr": 1971,
        "bezeichnung": "225-224",
        "eigentuemer_organisationstyp": "Gemeinde",
        "funktionhydraulisch": "Freispiegelleitung",
        "hydr_belastung_ist": null,
        "laengeeffektiv": 42.84,
        "leckschutz": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "totalFeatures": "unknown",
  "numberReturned": 1
}
```

Comment: please don't post **images** of text - it breaks accessability

Comment: my bad, changed to json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can by using the GeoJSON featureinfo templates (recent addition mind, should be available in 2.20.x, not sure about 2.19.x):
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/geojson.html

In the upcoming 2.21 it's also possible to [customize the attribute names directly in the UI](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#feature-type-details-vector)... but mind, using the names you're suggesting will break WFS solid (not a big deal if you're not using it anyways, turn it off in that case).

Comment: we are currently using 2.18.0 and only WMS so far.
I saw the template feature FreeMarker but it more hardcoded then i would have like it.
The new feature with 2.21 looks promising.